# Crystal Report not appearing in Visual Studio 2012/13 Add New Item

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I have installed Crystal report 2011 SP4 on my system where VS 2012 and 2013 are already installed. I don't see Crystal Report showing up in `Add New Item` -> `Reporting` dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this document https://www.tektutorialshub.com/install-crystal-reports-visual-studio/#Visual-Studio-2013-VS-2013 you might need a newer version of CR:

> **Visual Studio 2012 (VS 2012)**
>
> You can install SP 7 or higher.
>
> **Visual Studio 2013 (VS 2013)**
>
> Any version above the SP 9 is allowed