# How to add the Crystal Report on Visual Studio 2012 for web?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I download **CRforVS_13_0_20.exe** this version from this [link](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/install-crystal-reports-visual-studio/#Visual-Studio-2013-VS-2013). On that link they mentioned Visual Studio 2012 will support sp 7 or higher. So I download this **CRforVS_13_0_20.exe** version.

But I installed when I open my visual studion 2012 for web version, I cannot see the **crystal report** on add new item dialog box.

I saw this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431787/crystal-report-not-appearing-in-visual-studio-2012-13-add-new-item) also.